# Finding an "optimal" set of coin denominations

Tags: combinatorics

The U.S. dollar has five coin denominations under a dollar (1¢, 5¢, 10¢, 25¢, 50¢).

To make sure you can make exact change for any amount up to (and including) 99¢, I believe that the fewest number of U.S. coins an optimal pocket would need is nine; for example: { 1¢, 1¢, 1¢, 1¢, 5¢, 10¢, 10¢, 25¢, 50¢ } or { 1¢, 1¢, 1¢, 1¢, 5¢, 5¢, 10¢, 25¢, 50¢ } would do the trick.

My first question then is: is there a set of five coin denominations with which we can make exact change up to and including 99¢ with fewer than nine coins? If not (as seems to me to be the case), can we prove that we cannot do better than nine coins in a manner more succinct than simply trying all the cases?

---

Following on, with the U.S. coin denominations, it seems possible to cover exact change up to and including 104¢ with nine coins.

My second question: can we find a set of five coin denominations that maximises the range of values covered with exact change using an optimal bag of nine coins?

---

My third question: can we generalise these previous questions for arbitrary values (i.e., an arbitrary number of coin denominations and/or an arbitrary target value)?

---

(This question comes from general curiosity mixed with ignorance of related problems. It seems to me the optimal coin values should follow some exponential function, but I am not quite sure what the base or the power should be.)

Comment: Added to my answer to show that binary coins are always at least as good as any other configuration.

Comment: another Googley question?

Answer (score 7):

The following is a first stab at this problem.

If you have a fixed base $b$, then one can generate change up to $b^k-1$ with $k(b-1)$ coins.  For instance, in binary, one can generate change up to $\$1.27$ with single coins each of denomination $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64$ cents.  In ternary, one can generate change up to $\$2.42$ with two coins each of denomination $1, 3, 9, 27, 81$ cents.  And so on.

In that sense, the most bang for the buck (as it were) can be determined by identifying, for any given amount $M-1$ and base $b$, the required number of "stages" $k = \lceil \log_b M \rceil$, and then minimizing the number of coins $N = k(b-1)$.  That is, we minimize

$$
N = (b-1) \lceil \log_b M \rceil
$$

Note that this is something of an overestimate, since not all coins in the uppermost "stage" may be needed (for instance, for $\$1.00$ in ternary coins, we do not need two $81$-cent coins), but it will give us a general idea of the principles involved.  Let us avoid the discrete niceties of $N$ and instead minimize

$$
N_0 = (b-1) \log_b M
$$

and then

$$
\frac{dN_0}{db} = \frac{(1-b+b \ln b) \ln M}{b (\ln b)^2}
$$

Since both $\ln M$ and $b (\ln b)^2$ are positive in the range in question, minimizing $N_0$ amounts to finding $1-b+b\ln b = 0$.  But $1-b+b\ln b$ is also always positive, for $b > 1$, so our best bet (in discrete coins) is to choose the minimum $b$, which is $2$: We should use binary coins to minimize the number of coins needed to make change, for most amounts.  The number of coins needed is then

$$
N = \lceil \lg M \rceil
$$

where $\lg$ is log to the base $2$.  It would be an interesting exercise (which I will defer for the moment) to determine for which amounts other coin configurations outperform binary.

ETA: Returning to think about this again, I think it must be that no other combinations can ever outperform binary (in the sense of requiring fewer coins); they might require as many, but never fewer.

One way to see this is to consider the cases where $M-1 = 2^k$—that is, situations where we must make change for all amounts up to a power of $2$.  That is where binary coins are at their least efficient, since they include the single coin of that uppermost power of $2$, for a total of $k+1$ coins.  For instance, to make change for $16$ cents, we must include a $16$-cent coin.

In order to outperform that, however, we must somehow make change with some other configuration for all amounts up to $2^k$ using only $k$ coins.  But the number of non-empty subsets of a set of $k$ coins is only $2^k-1$.  Therefore, there aren't enough selections of coins to make change in a way that is better than binary coins, so binary coins are always (among) the best.

Therefore, the answers to the first two questions are:

**1.** Coins of $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64$ cents (seven in all) suffice to make change for any amount up to $\$1.27$, as noted above.

**2.** Nine coins, in binary configuration, suffice to make change for any amount up to $\$5.11$.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I need to read in more detail the first part, but regarding the second, just to draw attention to the fact that in the question, there are fewer denominations (5) than coins (9). In the case where the number of denominations can equal the number of coins, I agree binary is optimal for sure. But if we take 2 denominations and 3 coins, for example, then with denominations {1¢,3¢}, we can get to 9¢ with 3 coins. With {1¢,2¢}, we can only get to 6¢ with 3 coins. I think the first part of your answer addresses this case though. I need to look more carefully later.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I misunderstood the question slightly.  Let me give that some thought.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** Here we use *generating functions* to ease some calculations. For convenience only we omit writing the currency symbol.

Before we start to answer the questions, we look at OPs examples and derive corresponding generating functions.

> **Example 1:** Nine coins $\mathcal{A}=\{1,1,1,1,5,10,10,25,50\}$
>
> We can use up to $4$ one cent coins to change money. This can be written as $$x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4$$ The exponent $k$ of $x^k$ indicates the number of one cent coins used for exchange. Similarly we get for all coins
>   \begin{array}{rrl}
> 1,1,1,1\qquad&\qquad 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=&(1-x^5)/(1-x)\\
> 5\qquad&\qquad1+x^5=&(1-x^{10})/(1-x^5)\\
> 10,10\qquad&\qquad1+x^{10}+x^{20}=&(1-x^{30})/(1-x^{10})\\
> 25\qquad&\qquad1+x^{25}=&(1-x^{50})/(1-x^{25})\\
> 50\qquad&\qquad1+x^{50}=&(1-x^{100})/(1-x^{50})
> \end{array}
>
> We conclude:  The generating function $A(x)$ for the different amounts   which   can be obtained by  the numbers of the multiset $\mathcal{A}$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1-x^5}{1-x}&\cdot\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x^{5}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{30}}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{50}}{1-x^{25}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x^{50}}\\
> &=\frac{1-x^{30}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x^{25}}\\
> &=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{29})(1+x^{25}+x^{50}+x^{75})\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We see that some factors cancel out and obtain a representation (2) which nicely shows the amounts which can be obtained.

**Comment:** The left factor $1+x+\cdots+x^{29}$ of (2) multiplied with the term $1$ from the right factor shows that the amounts $\{0,1,\ldots,29\}$ can be generated. The multiplication with the second term $x^{25}$ gives $\{25,26,\ldots,54\}$, etc. We therefore get
\begin{align*}
\{0,1,\ldots,29\}\cup\{25,26,\ldots,54\}\cup\{50,51,\ldots,79\}\cup\{75,76,\ldots,104\}
\end{align*}

We see, that all amounts from $1$ up to $104$ can be generated and according to the non-empty intersection of the sets, the numbers
\begin{align*}
\{25,26,27,28,29\}\cup\{50,51,52,53,54\}\cup\{75,76,77,78,79\}
\end{align*}
can be generated in *two different* ways, e.g. $26=25+1=10+10+5+1$.

> **Example 2:** Nine coins $\mathcal{B}=\{1,1,1,1,5,5,10,25,50\}$
>
> Analogously to example 1 we obtain the generating function $B(x)$ for the different amounts   which   can be obtained by  the numbers of the multiset $\mathcal{B}$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1-x^5}{1-x}&\cdot\frac{1-x^{15}}{1-x^{5}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{20}}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{50}}{1-x^{25}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x^{50}}\\
> &=\frac{1-x^{15}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{20}}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x^{25}}\\
> &=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{14})(1+x^{10})(1+x^{25}+x^{50}+x^{75})\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude: The product of the two leftmost factors in (3) gives all amounts from $0$ up to $24$. Some of them $\{10,11,12,13,14\}$ can be generated in two different ways. Multiplication with the other terms $x^{25},x^{50}$ and $x^{75}$ of the rightmost factor gives all numbers up to $99$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \{0,1,\ldots,24\}\cup\{25,26,\ldots,49\}\cup\{50,51,\ldots,74\}\cup\{75,76,\ldots,99\}
> \end{align*}

With some help of generating functions we answer the first two questions and consider some aspects of the third question.

> **First question:** Can all amounts from $1$ up to $99$ be generated by a multiset $\mathcal{C}$ containing fewer than nine coins?
>
> Note, that we need in any case the four coins $\{1,1,1,1\}\subset \mathcal{C}$ to generate the amounts $\{1,2,3,4\}$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \{1,1,1,1\}\subset \mathcal{C}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \{1,2,3,4\}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}
> \end{align*}
>   To keep the number of coins small and to generate the amounts $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ we also have to put $5$ to $\mathcal{C}$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \{1,1,1,1,5\}\subset \mathcal{C}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \{1,2,\ldots,9\}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}
> \end{align*}
>   In order to get the amount $10$ and to keep the number of coins as small as possible we *have to* either add $5$ or $10$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \{1,1,1,1,5,5\}\subset \mathcal{C}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \{1,2,\ldots,14\}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad\frac{1-x^{15}}{1-x}\tag{4}\\
> \{1,1,1,1,5,10\}\subset \mathcal{C}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \{1,2,\ldots,19\}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad\frac{1-x^{20}}{1-x}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   Here we see that we need *at least* six coins to obtain the amounts from $1$ to $14$ resp. $19$. By the way, note that the polynomials in (4) have the shape
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}
> \end{align*}
>   which implies, that the coefficients of $x^k, 0\leq k\leq n-1$ are always equal to $1$ and the representation of the amounts so far is in both cases *unique*.
>
> Since we want to take only up to eight coins and we have to obtain the amounts up to $99$ we need either  $25$ and $50$ cent coins or two $50$ cent coins. But we see at a glance that none of the possible outcomes generate the amount $20$ (besides other amounts which are not generated).
>   \begin{align*}
> &\{1,1,1,1,5,5,25,50\}&\{1,1,1,1,5,10,25,50\}\\
> &\{1,1,1,1,5,5,50,50\}&\{1,1,1,1,5,10,50,50\}\\
> \end{align*}

**Conclusion:** We need *at least nine coins* in order to generate all amounts from $1$ up to $99$.

> **Second question:** Can we find a set of five coin denominations that maximises the range of values covered with exact change using an optimal bag of nine coins?
>
> We can proceed with (5) which provides a necessary configuration to uniquely obtain all amounts from $1$ up to $19$.
>
> We observe, we cannot add a $25$ or $50$ cent coin, since then we would not get all amounts from $1$ up to $19+25$ resp. $1$ up to $19+50$. We add $10$ to not miss any number and to obtain as many new numbers as possible.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \{1,1,1,1,5,10,10\}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad&\frac{1-x^{5}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x^{5}}\cdot\frac{1-x^{30}}{1-x^{10}}\\
> &=\frac{1-x^{30}}{1-x}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   We observe, that all amounts from $1$ up to $29$ can be *uniquely* obtained  due to the representation (6). So, this constellation represents the maximum of all configurations to reach amounts up to $29$ with $7$ coins.
>
> The next step is in order to avoid *gaps* and to obtain amounts as large as possible to append a $25$ cent coin, which gives all amounts up to $29+25=54$ (no longer always unique). Since we need amounts as large as possible and we already can obtain all values from $1$ to $54$ we can append a $50$ cent coin in the following step.
>
> We obtain this way the multiset $\mathcal{A}$.

**Conclusion:** Example 1 already provides the maximum constellation of a set of nine coins, giving all amounts from $1$ up to $104$.

> **Third question:** Can we generalise these previous questions for arbitrary values (i.e., an arbitrary number of coin denominations and/or an arbitrary target value)?
>
> When using generating functions, an arbitray target value $N$ and an arbitrary number of coin denominations, restricted to the standard coin set $(1,5,10,25,50)$ with multiplicities $(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5)$ is a polynomial $P(x)$ of the form
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{N}a_jx^j\\
> &=\frac{\left(1-x^{m_1+1}\right)\left(1-x^{5(m_2+1)}\right)\left(1-x^{10(m_3+1)}\right)
> \left(1-x^{25(m_4+1)}\right)\left(1-x^{50(m_5+1)}\right)}
> {(1-x)\left(1-x^{5}\right)\left(1-x^{10}\right)\left(1-x^{25}\right)\left(1-x^{50}\right)}\\
> \end{align*}
>   with $a_j>0, 0\leq j \leq N$.

I suppose that at least for some specific cases information can be deduced from the theory of *[cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)*.

Comment: Thanks Markus! The intent of my second question was a bit different though to what you answered ... while you take the same five coin denominations and ask if we can get past 104 with nine coins, my question was asking how far we can get with nine coins if we can change the denominations.

Comment: @badroit: You're welcome and ok, now I  see what you like  to know.  If you  look at $(4)$ and  $(5)$ of my  answer,  you will presumably   have  the  same  situation with any choice of coins. If e.g. your smallest coin greater than $1$ cent is $7$  cent, you need $7-1=6$ one-cent coins for exchange without gaps. Since we have no more than nine coins for use, candidates for the smallest coin greater than $1$ besides $5$ are $6$ and $7$. Any other candidates $> 7$ can be excluded. It shouldn't be too hard, to refine both situations. Generating functions may again be helpful. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

A simple heuristic is that we want to spread coins as evenly as possible.  If we are allowed $n$ coins of $d$ denominations, express $n=qd+r$ with $q=\lceil \frac nd \rceil-1$ and $1 \le r \le d$. We will have $r$ denominations with $q+1$ coins and $d-r$ denominations with $q$ coins.  We start with a coin of $1$ and each successive value is multiplied by one more than the number of coins of that value.  To have the maximum total value we have the smaller quantities of smaller coins.  The maximum value will then be $(q+1)^{d-r-1}(q+2)^r$ unless $r=d$ in which case the maximum value is $(q+2)^{r-1}$. With our parameters of $n=9,d=5$ we would have coins of $1,2,2,6,6,18,18,54,54$ which can make all values up to $161$.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might help resolve the open second question. I just wanted to note for the moment that when you say "*To have the maximum total value we have the smaller quantities of smaller coins*", I'm not convinced that is the case. With $1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 9, 27, 27, 81$, we end up with a sum of $161$ as well.